# Change from a NSMutableArray to a .plist

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsarray, plist

I have been working through several tutorials on uitableviews.

I have put, as instructed, all the info into a 'listofitems' as below

```
    listOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSArray *countriesToLiveInArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Iceland", @"Greenland", @"Switzerland", @"Norway", @"New Zealand", @"Greece", @"Rome", @"Ireland", nil];
NSDictionary *countriesToLiveInDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:countriesToLiveInArray forKey:@"Countries"];

NSArray *countriesLivedInArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"India", @"U.S.A", nil];
NSDictionary *countriesLivedInDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:countriesLivedInArray forKey:@"Countries"];

[listOfItems addObject:countriesToLiveInDict];
[listOfItems addObject:countriesLivedInDict];
```

This creates a sectioned table view.  I would like to know how to change it into a .plist instead of typing it all out into the RootViewController.m.  I would still like it to be in a sectioned tableview.

Is there a simple method for changing from this NSMutableArray,NSArray and NSDictionary to a plist?

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple method for this `writeToFile:atomically:`:

```
[listOfItems writeToFile:destinationPath atomically:YES];
```

This will automatically create a file with plist inside it.

Answer (score 0):

that sorta depends on what you want in a plist, and what you put into it. if the entries and contents are all CFPropertyList types (CFString,CFDate,CFData,CFDictionary,CFArray,CFNumber...) then just create it with something like `CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy`.

if you have non-convertible custom objects (e.g., your own NSObject subclasses), then see the cocoa archiving topics.

Comment: you may also use NSPropertyListSerialization

Comment: I would like the exact same values in a plist then to import it into the file.  So to produce the same outcome.

Comment: @Kurt Lane of course, see the documentation for the types CFPropertyList supports (it's that list, plus CFBooleanRef - and all those types are toll free bridged). therefore, if you put a collection object into the plist, every entry in the collection must also be one of the supported types. if you need to archive object representations beyond this list, then you'll have to support archiving/unarchiving by using only these types, or use foundation's archiving functionalities to archive more elaborate types objects. everything in your example (array, dictionary, string) is compatible with (cont)

Comment: CFPropertyList interfaces, and may be saved as xml or binary plist. so if you need to add a complex number (as an example), you will have to either a) create a dictionary and add a CFNumber for real and a CFNumber for imaginary (as one example), or b) teach your custom NSObject subclasses to serialize/deserialize themselves by implementing/adopting @protocol NSCoding. for your example, CFPropertyList is fine. if you have complex NSObject subclasses, it may be best to use NSCoder interfaces and implement NSCoding. for this simple case, you can use CFPropertyList or NSPropertyListSerialization.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple function end hear relization

This is function is updating NSArray

```
- (void) WriteRecordToFile:(NSMutableDictionary*)countDict {
    // Here to write to file
    databasePathCallCount = @"plist path";
    NSMutableArray *countArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:databasePathCallCount];
    if(countArray)
        [countArray addObject:countDict];
    [countArray writeToFile:databasePathCallCount atomically:NO];
}
```